# Content losing and Full version CKEditor 5

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor5

Please share your experience about using CKEditor 5.

1. Is HTML5 tags also removing like in CKEditor 4? In case yes, what can we do with it?
2. Show how we can enable all CKEditor 5 buttons and options on toolbar like in CKEditor 4. The following link contain Full Package with all options.

https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download/

Thanks for you time!

Answer (score 0):

> Is HTML5 tags also removing like in CKEditor 4? In case yes, what can we do with it?

CKEditor 5, unlike CKEditor 4, implements a custom data model. This means that every piece of content that you load into the editor needs to be converted to the model and then rendered back to the view.

Since conversion is done by plugins and is explicit (i.e. a feature tells exactly what HTML elements and/or attributes it converts to what model nodes) a piece of HTML which isn't covered by any of the loaded converters is simply dropped.

This means that if you want all of HTML5 to be supported, you need to write plugins to support them. Once you do that, CKEditor 5 won't filter anything out.

You can read more in the [CKEditor 5 Framework documentation](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/overview.html).

> Show how we can enable all CKEditor 5 buttons and options on toolbar like in CKEditor 4. The following link contain Full Package with all options.

Short note about CKEditor 4 – "full" is not "all". The "full" preset has a misleading name unfortunately. There are far more CKEditor 4 plugins than in "full" and you can browse them in the [Addons repo](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addons/plugins/all).

As for CKEditor 5, [existing builds](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5-builds/) come with a predefined set of features which reflect the use cases described by [Editor Recommendations](http://ckeditor.github.io/editor-recommendations/).

There are not many more plugins available right now because the project is in the early alpha version. However, you can check the [official list of features](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5#features) and [browse npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=ckeditor5-feature&page=1&ranking=optimal) to find more.

If you want to add or remove plugins from your editor, please read the [Creating custom builds guide](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/development/custom-builds.html).